# can't call member without object?

Tags: ros, kdl, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i'm using ros kinetic.

```
In file included from /home/robot/youbot_catkin_ws/src/youbot-controller/src/localisation-component.cpp:1:0:
/home/robot/youbot_catkin_ws/src/youbot-controller/src/localisation-component.hpp: In member function ‘virtual void Localisation::updateHook()’:
/home/robot/youbot_catkin_ws/src/youbot-controller/src/localisation-component.hpp:37:80: error: cannot call member function ‘void KDL::Rotation::GetQuaternion(double&, double&, double&, double&) const’ without object
             KDL::Rotation rot = KDL::Rotation::GetQuaternion(qu.x, qu.y, qu.z, qu.w);
                                                                                    ^
    youbot-controller/CMakeFiles/localisation-component.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'youbot-controller/CMakeFiles

/localisation-component.dir/src/localisation-component.cpp.o' failed
    make[2]: *** [youbot-controller/CMakeFiles/localisation-component.dir/src/localisation-component.cpp.o] Error 1
    CMakeFiles/Makefile2:407: recipe for target 'youbot-controller/CMakeFiles/localisation-component.dir/all' failed
    make[1]: *** [youbot-controller/CMakeFiles/localisation-component.dir/all] Error 2
    Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
    make: *** [all] Error 2
    Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

here is d source file:

```
#ifndef OROCOS_LOCALISATION_COMPONENT_HPP
#define OROCOS_LOCALISATION_COMPONENT_HPP

    #include <rtt/RTT.hpp>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <geometry_msgs/Pose2D.h>
    #include <geometry_msgs/TransformStamped.h>
    #include <kdl/frames.hpp>
    
    class Localisation
        : public RTT::TaskContext
    {
        geometry_msgs::TransformStamped tfs;
        RTT::OutputPort<geometry_msgs::Pose2D> outpose;
     public:
        Localisation(std::string const& name)
            : TaskContext(name, PreOperational)
        {
        addPort("pose", outpose).doc("Contains latest Youbot Pose.");
    }

    bool configureHook() {
        /** Check in here that we can call rtt_tf */
        return false;
    }

    void updateHook() {
        try {
            /* tfs = ...call rtt_tf and query the transform /odom to /base_footprint ... ; */
        } catch (...) {
            return;
        }
        geometry_msgs::Pose2D pose;
        pose.x = tfs.transform.translation.x;
        pose.y = tfs.transform.translation.y;
        geometry_msgs::Quaternion qu = tfs.transform.rotation;
        KDL::Rotation rot = KDL::Rotation::GetQuaternion(qu.x, qu.y, qu.z, qu.w);
        //KDL::Vector v;
        //pose.theta = rot.GetRotAngle(v);
        //outpose.write(pose); 
    }
};

#endif
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285134/can%27t-call-member-without-object?/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2018-03-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a C++ issue and not a ROS one: [KDL::Rotation::GetQuaternion(..)](http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/orocos_kdl/html/classKDL_1_1Rotation.html#a37f92d1b2c5e9708771543c521c276c4) is not a static method, but a regular one. From the documentation:

> Get the quaternion of this matrix

You'll need to first create an instance of `KDL::Rotation` ('this matrix') and then invoke its `GetQuaternion(..)`.

Note also: `x`, `y`, `z` and `w` are *output arguments*.

---

Edit:

> ```
> KDL::Rotation rot;
> ```

```
rot.GetQuaternion(qu.x, qu.y, qu.z, qu.w);
```

> stil i'm getting same error.

> error is:

> ```
> undefined reference to `KDL::Rotation::GetQuaternion(double&, double&, double&, double&) const'
> ```

So which is it? The same error, or this last one?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2018-03-13**:
KDL::Rotation rot;
rot.GetQuaternion(qu.x, qu.y, qu.z, qu.w);
stil i'm getting same error.

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2018-03-13**:
error is: undefined reference to `KDL::Rotation::GetQuaternion(double&, double&, double&, double&) const'

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2018-03-13**:
the full error is:
CMakeFiles/localisation-component.dir/src/localisation-component.cpp.o: In function `Localisation::updateHook()': localisation-component.cpp:(.text._ZN12Localisation10updateHookEv[_ZN12Localisation10updateHookEv]+0xee): undefined reference to` KDL::Rotation::Quaternion(double, dou

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-13**:
Please add this sort of updates to your original question. Use the `edit` button/link for that.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-14**:
The linker error would seem to be similar to what you ask about in #q285133.

If you've solved the "cannot call member function" error, then is this question answered?

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2018-03-14**:
well this error is done by using object of class kdl::rotation but when i do it, the previous error i.e `undefined reference to kdl::rotation::quaternion ..` is comming. so now i'm reinstalling ros desktop full this time. previously i was using ros kinetic not full version, and gazebo 9.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-14**:
If your question about "cannot call member function" was answered, then please tick the checkmark to the left of this answer.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-03-14**:\

> so now i'm reinstalling ros desktop full this time. previously i was using ros kinetic not full version, and gazebo 9.

I would be surprised if that will solve anything, but you never know.